# Outlook 2007 E-Mails come in blank or with <="" style=""> in the body, nothing else

Tags: email, exchange-2010, outlook

Basically users who have just been upgraded to Outlook 2007, are not receiving SOME emails (from outside our domain, ie hotmail, yahoo). It seems that maybe these emails are HTML based, and not sent in plain text. These emails come in, along with their attachments, subjects, to/from line, etc. But the body is blank except the words <="" style="">. If the same user goes into their webmail, iphone, blackberry instead, they can read the message fine.

It's clear to me that something in Outlook 2007 is not generating the body correctly, so it just strips it. I just don't know WHY.

Our mail server was recently upgraded to Exchange 2010, users outlook 2003 are working fine, it's just the random emails for users using 2007.

I hope I made that clear enough, thank you for any future help guys.

I've seen this post http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001972 regarding websense emails causing this issue. I don't believe this to be the problem. The emails come from outside our domain, they range from Hotmail, Yahoo, etc.

Comment: Are you on the latest SP of office 2007?

Comment: You know what, I'm not 100% on that. Is that a separate download or does it come in with windows updates...

Comment: It only comes in with windows updates if you have opted in for "additional" product updates.

Comment: I'm downloading SP2 right now, I'm going to put it on a users machine who was reporting this error frequently. I'll be sure to post results.

Comment: Everyone is running SP2, sadly. I was hoping for an easy fix. Still can't figure this one out.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is affecting all HTML emails or if it's affecting text and HTML emails?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen AV interfere with Outlook's message parsing, while the messages load fine over OWA. Try disabling their client AV and re-opening Outlook. If they display correctly, you've found your problem.